# Coldfusion - Google OAuth2.0 not working in hosted environment on Safari

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, railo, cfhttp

I am having an issue with the `Google OAuth` using `cfhttp` in Safari. It works in my local environment but on our hosted environment everytime I use google oauth, I get the return code below:

Error detail:

```
string  400 Bad Request
```

File content:

```
string  { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed." }
```

Header:

> string HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: application/json Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Date: Sat, 22 Nov 2014 01:38:30 GMT X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

```
    <cffunction name="getGoogleToken" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="Event" type="any">
    <cfargument name="code" type="any">
    <cfset var rc = Event.getCollection() />
    <cfscript>
        var postBody = "code=" & UrlEncodedFormat(arguments.code) & "&";
             postBody = postBody & "client_id=" & UrlEncodedFormat(rc.googleclientid) & "&";
             postBody = postBody & "client_secret=" & UrlEncodedFormat(rc.googleclientsecret) & "&";
             postBody = postBody & "redirect_uri=" & UrlEncodedFormat(rc.googlecallback) & "&";
             postBody = postBody & "grant_type=authorization_code";

    </cfscript>
    <cfhttp url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" method="post" result="result" charset="utf-8"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#postBody#"> 
    </cfhttp>               
    <cfdump var="#result#" />
    <cfabort>
    <cfreturn deserializeJSON(result.filecontent.toString()) />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Write a test page with a simplified cfhttp call with hardcoded values. Safari doesn't do the cfhttp request. It could be that Safari is doing two requests, the first of which is rendering the code expired.

Answer (score 2):

**"Code was already redeemed."** error means that you are trying to use an authorization code that has already been used. for example it call in two functions and therefore twice send a request for access token. Note that the given authorization code can be used only once.